# Pushing values into an array

Tags: javascript

When a value(person) is entered, the code create a `<li>` with the name of it. Multiple names, multiple `<li>`. I would also like to push all the values into `people` for future use.

```js
const addForm = document.querySelector('.add');
const list = document.querySelector('.todos');
let people

const generateTemplate = todo => {
  const html = `
    <li>
        <span>${todo}</span>
        <i class="far fa-trash-alt delete"></i>
    </li>`
  list.innerHTML += html;
}

addForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
  const todo = addForm.add.value.trim();
  e.preventDefault();
  if (todo.length) {

    if (people === null) {
      people = [];
    }
    people.push(todo);
    console.log(people)
  }
  generateTemplate(todo);
  addForm.reset();
  people.push(todo)

  console.log(people)
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Todolist</title>
</head>

<body>
  <form action="" class="add">
    <h1>Group generator</h1>

    <input type="text" id="name" name="add" placeholder="Enter name here">

    <input type="submit" value="submit them">
    <p>you can also press enter instead</p>

  </form>

  <ul class="todos">

  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `if (people === null)` won't be true. You didn't initialize `people`, so it's `undefined`, not `null`.

Comment: Why don't you just do `let people = [];` so you don't need that test?

Comment: Either do people == null, with two equals it checks if its null or undefined. Or you use people === undefined. Or you simply initialize people properly like @Barmar said. let people = [];

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `people===null` use `if (!people)`, because people is undefined at first time:

```
if (!people) {
      people = [];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>Todolist</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" class="add">
        <h1>Group generator</h1>

        <input type="text" id="name" name="add" placeholder="Enter name here">
    
        <input type="submit" value="submit them"> <p>you can also press enter instead</p>

    </form>

    <ul class="todos">
        
    </ul>


    <script>
const addForm = document.querySelector('.add');
const list = document.querySelector('.todos');
let people

const generateTemplate = todo => {

    const html = `
    <li>
        <span>${todo}</span>
        <i class="far fa-trash-alt delete"></i>
    </li>`
    list.innerHTML += html;
  
  

}

addForm.addEventListener('submit', e => {
debugger
    const todo = addForm.add.value.trim();
    e.preventDefault();
    if (todo.length) {
            
       if (!people) {
            people = [];
        } 
        people.push(todo);
        console.log(people)
    }
        generateTemplate(todo);  
        addForm.reset(); 
    people.push(todo)

    console.log(people) 


}); 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The use of user input in the template literal that's then assigned through innerHTML would open a cross-site scripting vector.

Comment: I would declare people properly by coding "let people = []", but assuming people is a response from an API, I would use if (people == null), it checks whether people is null or undefined. However your approach seems to be right too :)

Comment: @MrJami I absolutely agree with you, however I try to solve the issue without major  change :)

Comment: @Mic sorry I don't catch you.

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadi For example, enter `<img src=/ onerror=alert('xss') />` in the textbox and submit it.

Comment: @Mic Oh you mean `xss` attack?  Yes your right the code is not safe but OP's question is about `push`  methods of array.